JWT Bearer Token Authorization not working after upgrade to .NET 8
I realize there are many facing issues relating to upgrading to .NET 8, and I've done my best to see if the issue I am facing is related, but none of the solutions I've seen work for me and I haven't noticed anyone else facing quite the same issue.
I am unfortunately fairly ignorant when it comes to JWT and authentication, but let me explain what I do observe happening.
The code that works with .NET 7 is something like the following:
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };

options.Authority = KeyCloakOptions.Authority;
options.MetadataAddress = $"{options.Authority}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
options.RefreshOnIssuerKeyNotFound = true;
options.Audience = KeycloakOptions.AudienceInvoice;
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Authentication failed: " + context);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("JWT Bearer Token Validated.");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };

If I use this code, I will get an error about the issuer, something like:

IDX10204: Unable to validate issuer. validationParameters.ValidIssuer is null or whitespace AND validationParameters.ValidIssuers is null or empty.

This can be overcome by modifying TokenValidationParameters to include the issuer, via:
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        ValidIssuer = KeyCloakOptions.Authority
    };

I do not understand why this is now needed in .NET 8, but not in .NET 7. However, even so, after making the above change I will then get a similar error regarding the audience, something like:

IDX10208: Unable to validate audience. validationParameters.ValidAudience is null or whitespace and validationParameters.ValidAudiences is null.

And again, this can be overcome by modifying TokenValidationParameters to include the audience, via:
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        ValidIssuer = KeyCloakOptions.Authority,
        ValidAudience = KeycloakOptions.AudienceInvoice
    };

This will lead to the next error about the signing key. And for this one, I don't know what I need to do to make it work.
My main question, though, is why I now need to include things like Issuer, Audience and Keys in the TokenValidationParameters whereas before it worked fine as part of the options. It appears that some of the options, like options.MetadataAddress are being ignored in .NET 8, which is why I now need to explicitly specify the values in TokenValidationParameters.
Or perhaps a more fundamental question, is there something that I need to add/modify so that the same (or very similar code) that worked in .NET 7 will also work in .NET 8.
Thanks for any help,
Eric

Where these values for ValidIssuer etc. possibly defined in a config file in your .NET 7 system, and now that config file isn't available anymore / doesn't contain those values?

No, in fact, one of the values needs to be calculated as the value is dependent on the current tenant.

The following is working for me, which is good, though I don't have a clear understanding of why this change is necessary.  The fix is essentially to move all of the validation logic into TokenValidationParameters.
That is, the code is changed from:
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };

// These properties need to be moved to TokenValidationParameters 
options.Authority = KeyCloakOptions.Authority;
options.MetadataAddress = $"{options.Authority}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
options.RefreshOnIssuerKeyNotFound = true;
options.Audience = KeycloakOptions.AudienceInvoice;

to:
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
    ValidAudience = KeycloakOptions.AudienceInvoice,
    ValidIssuer = issuer,
    ConfigurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
        $"{KeyCloakOptions.Authority}/.well-known/openid-configuration",
        new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
        new HttpDocumentRetriever() { RequireHttps = false }
    )
};

My understanding is that this will give the equivalent behavior as that which I have now, but I would still like to understand why this change is necessary (assuming that this is the right change).

Using the ConfigurationManager property you can skip on setting the ValidIssuer yourself. It will be set using the openid config retrieved by the configuration manager.

There is a slew of aspnetcore github issues filed for this and similar token validation problems.
In most cases this is caused by Microsoft.IdentityModel.* package version mismatch. They need to be exactly the same version. But since this is not enforced by Nuget, you may end up with different versions of Microsoft.IdentityModel.* through transitive dependencies.
Run this:
dotnet list package --include-transitive | sls "Microsoft.IdentityModel|System.IdentityModel"

and manually upgrade IdentityModel.* packages of lower version to the most recent version used.
This is also discussed in the IdentityModel 7.0.0 announcement: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/IdentityModel-7x#reminder
Example github issues:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52075#issuecomment-2040705995
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52330#issuecomment-1976336097
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/2510#issuecomment-1974057433


Thanks @Sophia for a thorough and clear response.  I did notice that a couple of packages were 7.4.1 while most 7.5.1.  Unfortunately, though, after upgrading all of the packages to the same version (7.5.1), I am still getting the same error.

It feels like all of a sudden your old code cannot read KeyCloak discovery document so it can't find the valid issuer. This post here suggests that the package was choking on one of the subsections of the file - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52330#issuecomment-1968970660 But it appears that this was fixed in IdentityModel 7.4.1. You may want to try what the OP was trying, feed the discovery doc manually and see if there are any issues reading it.

While I was working on your suggestion above, I came to the realization that the discovery doc was not even being accessed at all.  The assignment to the MetadataAddress seems to be ignored.  Do you have any idea why that might be happening?  And really appreciative of your help. Thanks.

I was having the same issue. Make sure these two packages are using the same version.

This my third party JWT validation config
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.MetadataAddress = "https://localhost:7087/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience = "vue-client"
    };
});

